# Laravel 5 check role giving error "trying to get property of non object"

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel and am trying to implement roles to users.

1. I have created the Role table and Model associated with it
2. I have added a column `role` to the `users` table.
3. I am now trying to check that role in the `User` model

EDIT: After an answer/explanation here I changed `role` to `role_id` in the `users` table but I am still getting the same error.

Here is my User Model...

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Auth;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    // more stuff

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return $this->role->slug == 'admin';
    }

}
```

And my Role Model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Role extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

When I go to my admin page I have the following function...

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    if ($user->isAdmin()) {
        return view('admin/home_admin');
    }
    else {
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

However Im getting the error...

> Trying to get property of non-object  in User.php line 62 at
>   HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of
>   non-object', '/home/vagrant/Code/esearch/app/User.php', '62', array())
>   in User.php line 62

I have tried this while logged in and not logged in with the correct role. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: change your User to Guard in the last panel. That should be the fix you're looking for. Or you can just use straight `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code started off with the `role_id` setting that @user3158900 noticed. This was something that needed to be resolved.

But you were using the improper form of user when attempting to see what is happening. Instead of the `User $user` you need `Guard $user` or `Guard $auth` as it is more commonly seen. You can also use `Auth::user()->isAdmin()`.

There is one last thing that should be looked at that I did not mention in my comment above.

If the user is not logged in and is a guest you will get an error trying to find `Auth::user()` and it will fail. This is because `Auth::user()` is null when you are a guest. So you should do a check that is logged in.

You can either use `!Auth::guest()` or `Auth:check()` (which is cleaner).

Hopefully this is all good for you!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, im unsure which would be regarded as officially correct answer as both fixes were required.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Laravel assumes the foreign key for role to be `role_id` but since you are using `role`, you need to set that up in your relation as well.

<s>In your `Role` model.</s>

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'role');
}
```

In your `User` model.

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role', 'role');
}
```

Because `role` would both be a relating function and a column in your table, it would be best to modify the column name to `role_id` to match what Laravel expects.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although Im getting an error , Undefined property: App\User::$role  in BelongsTo.php line 74.

I double checked to make sure `role` was my column name in the users table but still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that the relationship name and the column name would be the same so when you try and use `$user->role` I'm not sure if it would return what's in the `role` column or the relationship you setup.  Is it at all possible to undo what I told you and just change the `role` table column to `role_id`?

Comment: I actually did that in the end, although I seem to be back to square one where Im getting the "trying to get property of non object" error which is very strange (this time with role_id being the column name). Ive a feeling its something small but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Can you make sure you have appropriate data in your database for this relation and also show us your `isAdmin` function?

Comment: I definitely have the correct data alright, I followed the comment above and that solved the issue. However, this error was inevitable due to using `role` in my table originally so this is a more relevent a correct answer to the question at hand.

Comment: Since you've done all the explaining in your answer, it's probably best if you mark that correct so as not to mislead people.